# Navigation Stopped Working After I Changed From Using Functions To Classes

Tags: react-native

My apologies if I randomly seem to change into Dutch in my code,  since it's my first language.

app.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from 'react-native-picker-dropdown';
import SignUp from './Signup.js';
import SignIn from './Signin.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn',{stack:Stack,navigation:navigation})}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SignIn navigation={navigation}></SignIn>
  );
}
function SignUp2({ navigation }){
  return(
    <SignUp navigation={navigation}/>
  );
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={DetailsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SignIn.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from 'react-native-picker-dropdown';
import SignUp from './Signup.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';


export default function SignIn({ navigation,stack }) {
  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style = {{fontSize:50, color:'#888'}}>Sign In</Text>
      
      <TextInput style = {styles.textinput} placeholder ="E-Mailadres" placeholderTextColor='#888'/>
      <TextInput style = {styles.textinput} placeholder ="Wachtwoord" placeholderTextColor='#888' secureTextEntry={true}/>
      <Text>{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} ><Text>Aanmelden</Text></TouchableOpacity><StatusBar style="auto" />
      
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style = {{color:'#888'}}>Nog geen account?  </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}> Registreren </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#339',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textinput:{
    alignItems: 'center',
    //paddingBottom:100,
    width : 300,
    borderBottomColor:"#888",
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    paddingTop:25,
    textAlign:'center'

    

  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10,
    width:300
  },
});
```

and finally the problematic page SignUp.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from 'react-native-picker-dropdown';
import * as Crypto from 'expo-crypto';
import { State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default class SignUp extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style = {{fontSize:50, color:'#888'}}>Sign Up</Text>
        <Picker 
          /*selectedValue={this.state.language}*/
          style={{ height: 50, width: 400,textAlign: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',paddingLeft: 50,}}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ language: itemValue })} color='#fff' placeholder="Selecteer een">
          <Picker.Item label="Selecteer Onderwijsinstelling" value="s1" color="#888"/>
          <Picker.Item label="School2" value="s2" color="#888"/>
        </Picker>
        <TextInput nativeID="naam" style = {styles.textinput} placeholder ="Naam" placeholderTextColor='#888' />
        <TextInput nativeID="email" style = {styles.textinput} placeholder ="E-Mailadres" placeholderTextColor='#888' />
        <TextInput nativeID="pw" style = {styles.textinput} placeholder ="Wachtwoord" placeholderTextColor='#888'/>
        <Text>{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}{"\n"}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} onPress={()=>SignUpAction()}><Text>Registreren</Text></TouchableOpacity><StatusBar style="auto" />
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style = {{color:'#888'}}>Al een Account?  </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn')}>
            <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}> Inloggen </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

 function SignUp1(/*{ navigation }*/) {
  /*state={
    email:null,pw:null,
  }*/
  
}
function SignUpAction(){
  alert("ik ben in de functie")
  
  
  
}
/* return fetch("http://192.168.2.66:80/api/ToDoItems/6043586d6968ead885283145")
  .then(response=>response.json()).
  then(responseJson =>{
   alert(responseJson)
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    alert(error)
    console.error(error)});function emailAlreadyExists(email){
  return fetch("http://192.168.2.66:80/api/ToDoItems").then(
    response=>response.json()
  ).then(
   // responseJson=>
  )
}*/
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#339',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textinput:{
    alignItems: 'center',
    //paddingBottom:100,
    width : 300,
    borderBottomColor:"#888",
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    paddingTop:25,
    textAlign:'center'

    

  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10,
    width:300
  },
});
```

since I've decided to change from using the function for signup to classes the navigation stopped working, I need to use the class since function pages seemingly lack any state capabilities, how do I fix the navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Classes you can access the `navigation` using `this.props.navigation`.
for example

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')
```

Also, you can use `state` in functions now through `react-hooks`. please see the reference https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html